# GKMinmaxStrategist not exploring required positions

Tags: minimax, alpha-beta-pruning, gameplay-kit, gkminmaxstrategist

Imagine a very simple game, where in any non-final position, the active player can make either move 1 or move 2.

Let's say if player 1 starts with move 1, he wins the game immediately. If he starts with move 2, he can still win if player 2 plays move 1, but loses if player 2 plays move 2.

```
value([1])   := win for player 1
value([2,1]) := win for player 1
value([2,2]) := win for player 2
```

Obviously, move 1 is the best move to make. Not only because it wins the game immediately, but also because player 1 isn't guaranteed a win if plays move 2 instead.

For any lookahead depth greater than 1, `GKMinmaxStrategist` wants to play move 2 though. Note that the strategist doesn't even seem to explore the possibility of player 1 losing the game, only the positions `[1]` and `[2,1]` are explored. It seems to me that `GKMinmaxStrategist` is pruning too many positions.

Am I missing something here?

You can find the sample project on [GitHub](https://github.com/jenox/GKMinmaxStrategist-Issues).